# Permission Denial: starting Intent not exported from uid

Tags: android

I came to this problem when I open an app which already installed in my phone from my own app .

> Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.qq.reader/.widget.picbrowser.PictureActivity } from
>   ProcessRecord{3823559b 16851:com.pax.market.android.app/u0a322}
>   (pid=16851, uid=10322) **not exported from uid** 10324

```
  public static void openApp(Activity activity,String packageName) {
    PackageInfo pi;
    try {
        pi = activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        Intent resolveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        resolveIntent.setPackage(pi.packageName);
        PackageManager pManager = activity.getPackageManager();
        List apps = pManager.queryIntentActivities(
                resolveIntent, 0);

        ResolveInfo ri = (ResolveInfo) apps.iterator().next();
        if (ri != null) {
            packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            String className = ri.activityInfo.name;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
            intent.setComponent(cn);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Package Name not found: " + e.getMessage() + ", App is not installed.");
    } catch (SecurityException e){
        SnackBar.newBuilder().activity(activity).
                text(activity.getString(R.string.permission_denied_to_open))
                .build().show();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: in my case  i open app B from app A.  And i cannot edit manifest in app B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List apps = pManager.queryIntentActivities(resolveIntent, 0);
more than one activity will  be found.

eg:appName: QQReader ,packagename:com.qq.reader .

you will find two activities:

com.qq.reader.widget.picbrowser.PictureActivity

com.qq.reader.activity.SplashActivity

PictureActivity cannot be started，since it's exported=false, SplashActivity can be started

code modified as below:

```
public static void  openApp(Activity activity,String packageName) {
PackageInfo pi;
try {
    pi = activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    Intent resolveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    resolveIntent.setPackage(pi.packageName);
    PackageManager pManager = activity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = pManager.queryIntentActivities(
            resolveIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo app: apps){

        Log.d(TAG,String.format("%s %s",app.activityInfo.packageName,app.activityInfo.name));
        packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
        String className = app.activityInfo.name;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        try {
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }catch(SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  /*  ResolveInfo ri = (ResolveInfo) apps.iterator().next();
    if (ri != null) {
        packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        String className = ri.activityInfo.name;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }*/
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Package Name not found: " + e.getMessage() + ", App is not installed.");
} catch (SecurityException e){
    SnackBar.newBuilder().activity(activity).
            text(activity.getString(R.string.permission_denied_to_open))
            .build().show();
}
```

}