# Display photo from FileProvider with Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I am working on a device running Android 8.1.0. I'm trying to open an image from a message attachment. I had a cache of image files working using a FileProvider a week ago and now it just stopped working without me touching the code. I'm trying to share an image from my internal app storage to Intent.ACTION_VIEW outside of my app. The photo viewer does launch, but there's a progress circle that just keeps spinning. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
void launchViewer(File f) {
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.company.secure.provider", f);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String mimeType =  Attachment.getMimeType(f.getName());
    //TODO Test to make sure this works on all devices...
    if (mimeType.startsWith("video")) {
        mimeType = "video/*";
    }

    if (mimeType.startsWith("image")) {
        mimeType = "image/*";
    }

    if(mimeType==null || mimeType.length()==0) {
        unknownMimeType(f.getName());
        return;
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if(resInfoList==null || resInfoList.size()==0)
    {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Error")
                .setMessage(String.format("Cannot find app to open file type(%s)",mimeType)).show();
        return;
    }
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: Do you have a crash stacktrace?

Comment: Use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard one.

Comment: @MatPag not sure how to add the stack on here so it's legible.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's what I had it doing before, I tried to broaden it to see if maybe I was missing a permission.

Comment: Edited the post with an image of the stack trace.

Comment: You should check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38987446/2910520

Answer (score 1):

So I just had to add the following line right before starting the activity.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

For some reason, the APK I shipped to testing that doesn't have this line in it works... but any new build does not work without this. I read that using the ResolveInfo method will only work for Lollipop and below and you will have to grant the permission directly to the intent. (Not sure how true this is). For this reason I left both permission granting methods in there to cover all bases. Thanks for all the help!